# Django forms: ForeignKey reverse inline / single form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, foreign-keys, inline

I have something like

```
# models.py

class Customer(Model):
    # ...

class Purchase(Model):
    customer = ForeignKey(Customer)
    # ...
```

And I need a single ModelForm to edit Purchase *together* with Customer fields. Ideally to play nice with Django admin.

What can I do?

P.S. Django doesn't seem to allow for it - not with any built-in stuff like admin inlines.

P.P.S. I would hate to code out all fields manually in PurchaseForm...

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've come up with this - it's a hack, but it works.

```
def InlineFormFactory(form_class, fk_name):
    """
    This can be used as a wrapper to enable inline form based on a foreign-key.

    Say you have something like

        class Customer(Model):
            # ...

        class Purchase(Model):
            customer = ForeignKey(Customer)
            # ...

    And you need a single form to edit Purchase *together* with Customer fields

    You can wrap CustomerForm and PurchaseForm like so:

        class CustomerForm(ModelForm):
           # ...

        @InlineFormFactory(CustomerForm, 'customer')
        class PurchaseForm(ModelForm):
           # ...

    This will add customer fields to the PurchaseForm, but will validate and save them to the foreign key object.

    When creating a new Purchase using the form, it will also create a new Customer. Can be used multiple times as well, e.g.

        @InlineFormFactory(CustomerForm, 'customer')
        @InlineFormFactory(ProductForm, 'product')
        class PurchaseForm(ModelForm):

    It will not remove the original `customer` field from the PurchaseForm - you can do so yourself in `Meta.fields`

    """

    def wrapped(base_class):
        attrs = {}
        for field in form_class._meta.fields:
            attrs['%s__%s' % (fk_name, field)] = forms.Field()

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            fk_form = form_class(instance=getattr(kwargs.get('instance'), fk_name, None))
            setattr(self, '%s_form' % fk_name, fk_form)
            if fk_form.instance:
                object_data = model_to_dict(fk_form.instance, form_class._meta.fields, form_class._meta.exclude)
                kwargs.setdefault('initial', {}).update({'%s__%s' % (fk_name, key): value for key, value in object_data.items()})
            base_class.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.fields.update({'%s__%s' % (fk_name, key): value for key, value in fk_form.fields.items()})
        attrs['__init__'] = __init__

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            prefix = "%s__" % fk_name
            fk_form = getattr(self, '%s_form' % fk_name)
            fk_form.cleaned_data = {}
            fk_form._errors = {}
            for key, value in self.cleaned_data.items():
                if key.startswith(prefix):
                    fk_form.cleaned_data[key.lstrip(prefix)] = self.cleaned_data[key]
            fk_form._post_clean()
            setattr(self.instance, fk_name, fk_form.save(commit=True))
            return base_class.save(self, *args, **kwargs)
        attrs['save'] = save

        newclass = type('%s%s' % (base_class, fk_name), (base_class,), attrs)
        return newclass
    return wrapped
```